# Is it safe to regularly purge kerberos ticket cache?

Tags: kerberos

When a computer is added or removed from an AD group, the computer usually needs to be rebooted to reflect the change.

Alternatively, one may run the `klist -li 0x3e7 purge` command to immediately clear the kerberos cache and force new tickets to be created.

I would like computers to reflect their group membership change more often. Perhaps every 8 hours. My question is, is it safe to purge the cache on a regular basis? Or is there a better approach (such as a GPO adjustment)?

I at first thought I would write a complicated powershell script to check what the local machine thinks its group memberships are and compare them to the live AD group membership. If a change is seen, then trigger a kerberos ticket purge. However, rather than that, I've considered simply running a scheduled task every 8 hours to purge the cache.

Should I expect any problems doing that? Will it interrupt anything in progress or have unintended consequences?

Comment: Isn't 10 hours already the maximum ticket lifetime in standard AD anyway?

Comment: Do not manually purge the cache. Instead, set the cache via `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Account Policies\Kerberos Policy` to a maximum of 300 (or less) minutes. However, this change may increase the load on the Domain Controller, depending on its size.

Comment: Safe? Sure. Necessary? No. Typically the ticket cache is purged as needed.

Comment: greg, i agree with you, but if someone likes to do so - but as always you hit the point

Comment: @GregAskew you are talking about a refresh. A refresh does not generate a new ticket. The refresh interval will not cause the group membership to update.

Comment: @djdomi you are referring to a refresh interval. A ticket refresh will not obtain new group memberships. Only a purge does that.

Comment: It is documented (although I'm having trouble finding it again - just read it last night) that neither the kerberos refresh or expiry window will generate a new ticket with new group memberships. Only a manual purge, or an actual reboot will do that.

Comment: yeh, that is the windows expected behavior, that you need to logoff and logon to fetch a group membership